# Using ndimage.interpolation.affine_transform for matrix translation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to translate a simple matrix using `ndi.interpolation.affine_transform`, but the result I get is reversed. For instance:

```py
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
m = [[1, 1, 11], [2, 2, 22], [3, 3, 33]]
final_affine_matrix = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
final_offset = [0, 1]
x = ndi.interpolation.affine_transform(
        m,
        final_affine_matrix,
        final_offset,
        order=1,
        mode='nearest',
        cval=0)
print(x)

[[ 1 11 11]
 [ 2 22 22]
 [ 3 33 33]]
```

Given that offset is `[0, 1]`, shouldn't the y-axis be shifted rather than the x-axis? That is, shouldn't the output be:

```
[[ 2  2 22]
 [ 3  3 33]
 [ 3  3 33]]
```

I can achieve that result, but only with the offset `[1, 0]`. Shouldn't they be the other way around?

Comment: When you post some code, make sure people can copy paste it and reproduce your result without having to do any extra effort in googling what to import to make it work. What is `ndi`?

Comment: @Bazingaa Sorry, that's fixed now. It's `scipy.ndimage`.

Comment: What `scipy` version do you have?

Comment: @norok2 I'm on 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html), `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform()` computes the new position by doing: `np.dot(matrix, o) + offset` (where `o` is the output position).

This means that the following tests should succeed:

```
m = np.array(m)
assert(m[0, 1] == x[0, 0])
assert(m[0, 2] == x[0, 1])
assert(m[1, 1] == x[1, 0])
assert(m[1, 2] == x[1, 1])
assert(m[2, 1] == x[2, 0])
assert(m[2, 2] == x[2, 1])
```

or, more concisely:

```
assert(np.all(m[:, 1] == x[:, 0]))
assert(np.all(m[:, 2] == x[:, 1]))
```

and they do, as expected. So, indeed the matrix is being shifted by the `1`-index. Perhaps, you were expecting the other matrix as output because you were confused by the printed output. The zeroth index denotes the rows, the first denotes the columns. Hence, shifting by the first index will shift columns.